# Tray icon not showing for application when running as Remote App

Tags: c#, trayicon, tray, remoteapp

I've created an application in C# that displays an icon in the tray, this works fine running on my local desktop.

When I run the application as a "RemoteApp" the tray icon never appears. Is there something I've done wrong, or is this even possible?

Comment: What GUI-technology are you using? Forms, WPF? Also, what kind of remotesoftware are you using? Feed us some more infos please

Comment: This problem does not look researched well, googling "remoteapp notification tray icon"  reveals [Yuan Wang's answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4122521f-7896-4098-a723-858077a243f1/remoteapp-notification-area-icons-not-visable?forum=winserverTS) at the MSDN forums.  He convincingly explains that the terminal server doesn't run Explorer and documents a registry tweak for its replacement, rdpshell.  Ask at serverfault.com if you still have problems.

Comment: Also, what versions of Windows OS are you running on both client and server?

Comment: Using Forms and just Windows Remote Apps. Win10 clients, Server 2016. @HansPassant Yes I did read that, the registry hack doesn't fit my needs and he somewhat alludes to some other approach which I was hoping someone could explain further. Thanks

Comment: Well, terrific job on telling us what you know and sharing what you already tried.  I will be very surprised when somebody here is willing to risk his considerable ESP powers at this shoddy question.  If you don't care enough about your problem then we don't have to care either, call Microsoft Support.

Comment: Wow sarcasm and snark on the internet how notable. The question was simple. All I asked for was someone with more experience to say: "Yes it's possible, look here" or "No its impossible due to this".

When I was asked for more information I willfully provided it, I see no reason for your vitriol unless you're just a troll.

Comment: Based on this question, I think it should be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157773/why-doesnt-the-tray-icon-context-menu-work-for-my-remoteapp

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible for an application running through remote app to display a tray icon on the client computer. Windows remote apps are just a specialized form of Remote Desktop Connection (try hitting Alt-Ctrl-End on one and you'll see the logout/task manager options for the server the app is actually running on). As such your application does not have access to the operating system services of the client computer, and thus can't put an icon in the system tray.
We have something similar at my office. We have an ERP system setup as a remote app on one of our servers that everyone uses and we have to install a program on each of the client computers to allow the program running through Remote App to access the client computer's hard-drive. And even then, when you go to save a file on the app, the "c" drive that comes up is the "c" drive on the server (they have to select their local hard drive separately).